# Send curl POST Request in Python without installing a lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, curl, post

I wanna send a curl post request in python. But I can't install any lib like 'request'. I could send POST request like following example :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d {\"username\":\"myusername\",\"password\":\"mypassword\"} https://example.com/login
```

I need equal code as the above in python2. Then, i must read what it returns. I'm working on Windows 10.

Comment: Have a look at [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)

Comment: When I  import urllib.request then I am getting  "ImportError: No module named request" error. I can't install any lib.

Comment: If you are on Python 2, try [urllib2.urlopen](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/urllib2.html)

Comment: like same error ImportError: No module named urlopen

Comment: You are supposed to import `urllib2` and use the function `urllib2.urlopen`

Answer (score 0):

Write a curl command in a way that it can work in the shell and then execute the command in the shell.
This way you don't need the requests package.

```
import os
command = "curl -u {username}:{password} [URL]"
os.system(command)
```

Comment: Could you help me how can i convert above example? I couldn't do it.

Comment: check here if your code is running on linux: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/curl-command-in-linux-with-examples/

Comment: No, i am working on Windows10. I added as a note it.

Comment: in that case, you have to install cUrl in the windows terminal shell. I guess that won't be viable.

Comment: No,  we can think  just restriction on python side.